# How to make Cubic Stripes uv mapping

Tags: texturing

How can I make this striped pattern with wave texture in Blender?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm don't think the wave texture is the best fit.

You could however use math nodes to recreate the effect by transforming the x and y coordinates.

[image: node setup]

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this way

Comment: The bottom left multiplys second field contains `-1`